# Longest run of heads

Tags: pr.probability, computational-complexity

Consider $n$ independent tosses of a fair coin; the sample space has $2^n$ elements. Let $R_n(x)$ be the length of the longest run of heads in outcome $x$. We know that $$E[R_n]=\Theta (\log n)$$
[csun.edu/~hcmth031/research.html](http://csun.edu/~hcmth031/research.html)

Can we pair outcomes such that for every pair $(x,y)$, we have  $\max$ {$R_n(x),R_n(y)$}$=\Omega(\log n)$.

In case of partition into groups of two elements is impossible, can it be done if we divide the sample space into groups of no more than $k$ elements ($k$ is const)?

Comment: Yes. The longest run of heads is tightly concentrated. That means that almost all of the space has between $(1-epsilon)log n$ heads and $(1+epsilon)log n$ heads. 

All you have to do is pair the very small part of the space where $R_n(x)<(1-epsilon)\log n$ with an arbitrary $y$ in the part where $R_n(y)>= (1-\epsilon)\log n$. When this is done, pair the remaining stuff arbitrarily.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But can we have an explicit matching. I mean a explicit bijective map $\sigma(x)=y$ matching $x$ to y.

Comment: What does this have to do with computational complexity? 

Comment: @DouglasZare maybe the complexity of computing such a pairing, see e.g. the pairing in my answer.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas what do you think of the complexity aspect?

Comment: @Bjørn: Not really my area of expertise, but: I suspect you can probably do something rather crude to get a matching where one of the terms has a guaranteed $(1-\epsilon)\log n$ string of repeated heads. I am reminded of the work of Terry Soo on constructing matchings of Poisson processes.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer is a followup to Anthony Quas' comment and your subsequent request for an explicit map.]

Let's list all the outcomes as $x_1\prec x_2\prec\dots\prec x_{2^n}$ in the following order:

$x$ precedes $y$ ($x\prec y$) if either $R_n(x)< R_n(y)$, or $R_n(x)=R_n(y)$ and $x$ preceeds $y$ lexicographically.

Then partition the sample space into the pairs $\{x_i, x_{2^n+1-i}\}$, $1\le i\le 2^{n-1}$.

To see that this works we use the results of Boyd that $E(R_n)\ge \log_2 n-c_1$ and $\text{Var}(R_n)=\sigma^2_n\le c_2$ for constants $c_1$, $c_2$ (see e.g. [Schilling's MAA paper](http://gato-docs.its.txstate.edu/mathworks/DistributionOfLongestRun.pdf)).

Namely, by Chebyshev's Inequality,
$$\mathbb P(R_n\le \log_2n -c_1-k\sqrt{c_2})\le \mathbb P(R_n\le E(R_n)-k\sigma_n)\le \frac{1}{k^2}$$
hence
$$\mathbb P(R_n\le \log_2n -c_1-2\sqrt{c_2})\le\frac{1}{4}<\frac12.$$
So
$$\max\{R_n(x_i),R_n(x_{2^n+1-i})\}\ge \log_2n -c_1-2\sqrt{c_2}=\Omega(\log_2n)$$
as desired.